# Solve Recurrence Equation T(n) = 2T(n/4) + √3

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, asymptotics, recursion

I've been struggling to come to exact solution for this. I'm using Recursion tree to solve this. Which is giving me θ(n) as an answer.

Steps : =>

```
            1) T(n) = 2T(n/4) + √3

            2) Emerging Pattern => (1/2^k) * n 

            3) Considering , when we break down to T(1) : :   (1/2^k) * n  = 1

            4) k = log (n)

            5) Each level has 2^i nodes :: 2^(log (n)) :=> n

            6) If you sum up cost , n + n/2 + n/4 + ..... = n*(1/1-(1/2))
```

Which is incorrect ,

Answer given is ( √n log n ) , would appreciate any help regarding same ?

Comment: Well, there must be some sort of $\log$ nature to the solution, as this gives $n$ growing exponentially in the recursive sequence.

Comment: well i think this here is the solution $$\left\{\left\{a(n)\to c_1 2^{\frac{\log (n)}{\log (4)}-1}-\sqrt{3}
   \left(1-2^{\frac{\log (n)}{\log (4)}}\right)\right\}\right\}$$

Comment: What are the initial conditions? Is it just that T(1) = 1?